# Creating a wifi hotspot on OSX with a connected USB wifi adapter instead of airport (OSX Lion)

Tags: wifi, usb

I am using a USB wifi adapter on my Lion imac.  I am trying to use that connection to create a working wifi hot spot with the imac's internal airport.

I tried following these instructions:
http://maketecheasier.com/create-wifi-hotspot-using-mac-os-x/2009/10/20

It didn't work, though. It feels like i need to do one more step to get the connection bridged between the usb adapter and the airport.

Thanks,
zeem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will only work on wifi adaptors that support bridged mode wireless. Not all of them do. The internal Airport does which is why it can be turned into a hotspot.

I think you'll be able to go this way

```
Share your connection from : [usb wifi adaptor] 
To Computers using : [airport]
```

Setting up all security features as per normal.

Comment: seems like this is the answer, but it looks like the adapter doesn't support what's needed. thanks for the help.